# "Metering" vs "measuring"

Tags: meaning, differences

I am now working on a technical concept of measuring of some data and I often see terms *measuring* and *metering*.

My understanding is that with a meter I measure.
But what is *metering*? And how does it differ to *measuring*?

When I am trying to google the difference, I am finding many articles using simply *measuring* and *metering* together.

Comment: Thanks all for explaining this! Now I know that I actually don't want to measure but meter :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, *measuring* is a one-time operation, while *metering* usually means measuring or keeping track of some quantity either continuously or periodically.

Comment: Ah, right, I even have that in my meter explanation.

Comment: Does it also apply to meter reading? eg. water meter,etc.

Comment: Yes. Gasoline, water, air, electricity

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

**Measuring** is mostly used to ascertain the dimensions, quantity, or capacity of something
and
**Metering** is mostly used in supplying a given amount of something using a 
[meter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metering) which according to the free dictionary is

> Any of various devices designed to measure time, distance, speed, or intensity or indicate and record or regulate the amount or volume, as of the flow of a gas or an electric current.

But as mentioned by Peter, the metering can be measuring the supply too

Answer (score 1):

Metering associates with the continuos flow of a commodity or product that  and is difficult to batch measure.  At the point of use, electricity, natural gas, and water are continuously metered and totalized.  The total amount used within a period of time, usually a month, is then multiplied by the commodity charge plus a tariff for the some or all of the local, state and federal governments.  The dispension of gasoline and diesel fuel oils are another example of metering.

Measuring associates with the dispensing of a proucuct in a single batch.  When one orders at the deli counter, the products are dispensed by weight which is measured.  Also, most of the packaged food products purchased at a supermarket are premeasured either by weight or volume.  A cup of coffee is another product that is measured and not metered.

Answer (score 1):

Metering is data acquisition that is read directly from the interface. Hence there's meter reading proof.

Measuring is data acquisition that is read indirectly from the interface. Indirectly means the interface provides indicative value for further data processing method or algorithm. Hence there's only indicator proofs available.

Comment: Can you tell us who uses this distinction? I'm not familiar with it. If I read a tape measure, I get a direct result, do I not? That is measuring, not metering. So you need to restrict the scope of the answer to some special domain.